# C# write into textbox (which is the Console Output) from Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, console-output

I am making a GUI to a bigger program.
In order to include a Abort button, i had to use Backgroundworker.

```
void _oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {           
            try
            {
                Starter.Handling(cBLog, cBSelC, cBSelT);
                if (_oWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message,"Exception Caught:");
            }
        }
```

Now however I have stumbled upon a bigger problem, not beeing able to access the Textbox which is loaded as follows:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Instantiate the writer
        _writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(txtConsole);
        // Redirect the out Console stream
        Console.SetOut(_writer);
    }
```

The Problem is, the TextBox has to stay the Console Output since I don't want to change the subprograms (which also contain while loops).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try clarifying your problem.

Comment: you need to make it threadsafe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)